# An explanation on variances

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble understand what the following represent.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers (i.e. $1X1$ matrices), do you understand what they mean?

Comment: I am studying multivariate normal distributions so they are row vectors

Comment: They should be column vectors so that the variance and covariance are matrices.  That is standard usage.

Comment: @CalvinLin : In $\TeX$ you can write $1\times1$ instead of $1X1$.  There's no need to use the letter $X$ like that.  In a way, that's the main point of $\TeX$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I would normally have used \times. I'm not sure why I used X instead.

Comment: @KaneBlackburn The underlying question is, do you understand what variance and covariance is? If you do, then these are the variance and covariance values in matrix form.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\mathbb X^{p\times 1}$ denotes a column vector of random components $X_i,i=1(1)p.$ Then the expectation of $\mathbb x$ is defined as $$E(\mathbb X)=E\begin{pmatrix}X_1 \\ \vdots\\X_p\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}EX_1 \\ \vdots\\EX_p\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1 \\ \vdots\\\mu_p\\\end{pmatrix}=\mathbb{\mu}
$$
Define $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=E[(X_i-EX_i)(X_j-EX_j)^T]=\sigma_{ij}$. We extend the **variance notation** to the **p-dimentional random vector $\mathbb X$** by the following matrix: 
$$E[(\mathbb X-E \mathbb X)(\mathbb X-E \mathbb X)^T] \\=E[(\mathbb X- \mathbb \mu)(\mathbb X-\mathbb \mu)^T] \\=E\left[\begin{pmatrix}X_1-\mu_1 \\ \vdots\\X_p-\mu_p\\\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X_1-\mu_1& \cdots &X_p-\mu_p\\\end{pmatrix}\right]\\=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_{11} &\sigma_{12} &\cdots &\sigma_{1p}\\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\\sigma_{p1} &\sigma_{p2}&\cdots& \sigma_{pp}\\\end{pmatrix}=\Sigma$$ In similarly way co-variance between $X$ and $Y$ is defined.

That's all from me.

Comment: Please, not $\sigma$ to denote covariances and variances (variances are usually $\sigma^2$, not $\sigma$).

Comment: @did Notation is for subject but subject is not for notation. $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2$ is merely a notation and anybody can define a notation in his own way. Sorry I don't think you need to object if I define variance of $X_i$ by $\sigma_{ii}$.

Comment: This is deeply untrue. In principle one is free to denote any object by any symbol one likes. However, especially in a teaching context, it is misleading to use a notation so close to, and yet different from, the accepted one. If you want to express your free will here, at least choose some symbol markedly different from $\sigma^2$, or go back to the general practice to denote by $M_{ij}$ the coefficients of a matrix $M$, thus use $\Sigma_{ij}$. But not $\sigma_{ij}$.

Comment: @Did: I am not a teacher. I am a student under Calcuttta University. Lastly I studied in the manner I answered this question. I am not an expert at all. It's my personal view that there is not a big deal if I use $\sigma_{ij}$.But since I am a student I may be wrong.

Comment: OK. Then change the thing.